# Why "Allowed memory size exhausted"?

Tags: php, memory

I am writing a batch script and get a `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` error.

I don't understand why the memory is filling up. I tried unsetting the `$row` variable, but that didn't change a thing. Here is my code:

```
// ... (sql connection)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM large_table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'] . PHP_EOL;
    unset($row);
}
```

(simplified code)

Why does the memory fill up, and how can I avoid it?

Note: this is a batch script. This is normal that I have to handle data like that (go through 1 million lines).

**Update: The out of memory happens around the 400 000th line, so this has got to be something in the loop? I'd like to avoid having to implement the paging if possible.**

Comment: It doesn't look like you should run out of memory from that code snippet. Is there some other variable that is growing each iteration?

Comment: will not the mysql query actually return the whole table -> meaning the result will be counted to the used memory?

Comment: Might be a silly suggestion, but it's the only thing I can think of: maybe you could try to flush your output buffer?

Comment: @rfausak Nothing more in the loop :(

Comment: @KillerX see the update to the question

Comment: Interesting. Due to the fact that you are using unset, the memory should not really be increasing after the 1st iteration of the loop. I am just curious what happens if you use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php (mysql_unbuffered_query())

Comment: @Matthieu Just because that's where you run out of memory doesn't mean that's where the problem is.

Comment: @levi-morrison I am not so verset in the actual internal workings of PHP but if you are able to provide a more detailed exploitation I would be very interested as to how else the memory would increase

Comment: @KillerX I'm pretty sure this is the issue here.. you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @LeviMorrison yeah, that's why it's a question, not a statement

Comment: Downvote and close vote, please explain?

Comment: @Matthieu - if you get time, do a runtime comparison of the unbuffered vs. the paged/buffered version? That would be interesting on 1m rows!

Comment: @halfer Good idea. I have 640 000 lines (and used an empty `while` block). With the unbuffered query it took between 2.1s - 2.2s. With the standard (buffered) query, I got the error around the 400 000th line (so less lines scanned), but it always took more than 2.3s to get there. So it's not reliable results at all (this is my laptop), but it *seems* faster without the buffering, maybe because the process doesn't go "filling" the memory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php (mysql_unbuffered_query()) to prevent the whole table being loaded into memory, but still avoiding pagination.

Comment: That did it! Your intuition was right, and I like it it answers the root of the problem.

Comment: btw I don't understand the downvotes without explanations... I upvoted to compensate

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right approach, but +1 since it does answer the original question :)

Comment: This seems to be the "proper" way, although I haven't heard of it before. Props

Comment: To tell the truth I do not have any experience with the function so I do not know if there are any pitfails that you might run into later, like  the MySQL connection dying in the middle of processing. If someone reading this knows about any problems of that kind, please post, it would be interesting to know about it :)

Answer (score 5):

Limit your query to for example 1k results and execute it again (with the offset ofcourse) until you've gone through all the table.
Your current unset makes no difference, since $row gets overwritten with each while iteration, so you can skip it.

```
$chunk_size = 1000;
$done = 0;

$keep_asking_for_data = true;
do{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `large_table` LIMIT {$done}, {$chunk_size}");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows){
        $done += $num_rows;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "{$row['id']}\n";
        }
    } else {
        $keep_asking_for_data = false;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}while($keep_asking_for_data);
```

Just compiled on my head, hope it works =D

Comment: I tried adding the unset to force the collection of the memory used by the variable, which is not guaranteed else (PHP GC). Anyway, see the comment to the other answer and the question update

Comment: Damn! "I'd like to avoid having to implement the paging if possible." This wasn't there when I made the code :D

Comment: @PalmTree Yep sorry about the update ;), +1 for the effort. Without the solution of KillerX I would have taken that code gladly now the work is done ;)

Comment: [Appreciation](http://mthruf.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/job-fails-whats-this-appreciation-you-speak-of.png)

Comment: Upvote for a more "conventional" solution than what I posted.

Comment: I think using the unbuffered query is a better solution - requires far less mucking around.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, page your results so you don't exhaust your available memory. MySQL itself is taking up this memory with your database resultset. Have a look at the following link, in particular the `LIMIT offset, limit` syntax of `SELECT`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: That was an idea but I confess I was too lazy to do it :p. Anyway, the error happens around the 400 000th line (see question update) so it may be something in the loop that maybe I can fix?

Comment: Your approach as it stands *ought* to buffer some results - removing buffering so paging becomes unnecessary is probably not the way to do it, imo. Anyway it should be easy now - @PalmTree has done it for you :)

Comment: Why do you think removing paging is not the good way to do it?

Comment: No, I think paging should be added in; it's removing buffering that I felt was not the right approach. Removing buffering will (presumably) reduce its performance - this is fine if it is for good technical reasons, but being too lazy isn't one of them ;-)

Comment: Would have posted a 'copy' of your answer, but I can only speak in code lines :D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a large database. I ran out of memory, despite unsetting the $row variable at about 400,000 records, but the unbuffered query fixed it.

Just for reference for others (and me when I do it again!), some unbuffered query example code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT SEQ, RECTYPE, ROSTERGRP, EMPNM, EMPNUM, DT, RDUTYCAT, ADUTYCAT FROM " .
        $tblRosters . " ORDER BY EMPNUM,DT";
$result  = mysql_unbuffered_query( $sql, $dbConn );
$svRow = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
    {
         // your processing code here
    }
    // Unset, close db etc. if you are finished goes here.
```