# Memory limit exceeded with PHP foreach

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

I'm attempting to foreach through many thousand items in an array, do some operations and save some values to a mysql table.

However, as I loop through, the memory usage continually grows until we run out of the memory I specify in php.ini, which is pretty quick.

I've tried using unset, setting variables to null and looked at garbage collection, but nothing is having an impact.

Is there a more efficient way I can loop through these elements (ie so the memory usage does not continually grow).

Below is a simplified example of what I'm doing.

```
foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber)
{
    $member = new Member($subscriber['id']);
    if ($member['id'] > 0)
    {
        $bulletin = Bulletin::getCustomBulletin($member['id']);

        Bulletin::compileBulletin($member['email'], time(), $bulletin['title'], $bulletin['content']);

        echo $member['email'] . "\n";
        echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

This produces the following results:

```
an@email.com
11336688
an@email.com
12043640
an@email.com
12749952
```

Comment: What is the memory limit in your php.ini?

Comment: I've moved it anywhere from 32MB to 512MB. I'm only testing on my local machine at the moment. I know that any reasonable choice made in php.ini will be too small though.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the Member object instantiation with just a static lookup function that returns the details you need? You could even try replacing the line with a static array and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: do not load all to an array($subscribers) .use [unbuffer query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php) or XMLreaders for large data processing.

Answer (score 2):

Is `$suscribers` a result of a DB query?

If so, it may be the source of your problem: the rows will be buffered in memory, even though you go through them one at a time.

You can try using [unbuffered queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php) or limit the number of results for the query and execute several smaller queries.

See also: [Why "Allowed memory size exhausted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243070/why-allowed-memory-size-exhausted)

Comment: Yeah it is. Its isn't particularly expensive as an operation though, ie only pulls out an id key and an id per user. What would you say was a good way of executing several smaller operations? I've tried a for loop where I update an offset and a limit on each loop, but that resulted in no improvement in memory management.

Comment: @AndyTait Yes that was what I was suggesting, if it doesn't work then that's probably not it (it worked for me on a similar issue). Are you fetching a *lot* of `$suscribers`?

Comment: Maybe try the unbuffered query?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing suspect about your `foreach` loop (no variables to be unset as they are all being written over on each iteration). You will need to find out which line is causing the memory grabs. A profiler found in a professional IDE would help with this. If you do not have access to one, you'll want to use `memory_get_usage()` as you've been doing but put it after every line to check which one is causing the bottleneck.

There are also free profiling tools such as [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: I have xdebug and webgrind installed. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to show which functions are taking the most time.

I suspect I will need to find a new way of achieving this altogether, ie a smaller set of data to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's hard to tell from the code that you've posted as there's no clue as to what the Member object does internally, but this looks to be a possible:

[recursive references leak memory](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33595)

I would eliminate the new member object creation in the code above to check whether that is the source of the memory leak. From what you've said, creating the member object may be unnecessary anyway and it could be replaced with a static lookup member function.

Comment: The trouble is, there is hundreds of lines of code within Bulletin::getCustomBulletin() and Bulletin::compileBulletin(). So I think I need to find a way of killing the memory swallowed after each iteration around the loop.

Comment: I think those are fine, but if there are any references to other objects in the `Member` class, then when you create the new member objects within the loop the memory won't be freed. It could be worth writing a static member function in the `Member` class to fetch just the details you need for the loop e.g. `Member::getMemberDetails($subscriber['id'])`.Static calls should be fine, which is why the Bulletin class shouldn't need to be touched.